# Disabling system animations make UI test fail Espresso?

Tags: android, android-espresso

My device: Samsung S8

The documentation of [Espresso setup instructions](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/setup#set-up-environment) say that

> To avoid flakiness, we highly recommend that you turn off system animations on the virtual or physical devices used for testing

I followed Android UI testing tutorial from this [Android Testing Codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-testing/index.html#6). But the test fail when i turn off the system animations. Instead the test passed when i turn on the system animations.

Animation: **on**

```
Testing started at 7:44 PM ...

11/06 19:44:43: Launching addNoteToNotesList()
No apk changes detected since last installation, skipping installation of D:\Android\Exercise\android-testing-step-1-5\app\build\outputs\apk\prod\debug\app-prod-debug.apk
No apk changes detected since last installation, skipping installation of D:\Android\Exercise\android-testing-step-1-5\app\build\outputs\apk\androidTest\prod\debug\app-prod-debug-androidTest.apk
Running tests

$ adb shell am instrument -w -r   -e debug false -e class 'com.example.android.testing.notes.notes.NotesScreenTest#addNoteToNotesList' com.example.android.testing.notes.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
Client not ready yet..
Started running tests
Tests ran to completion.
```

Animation: **off**

```
Testing started at 7:51 PM ...

11/06 19:51:04: Launching addNoteToNotesList()
No apk changes detected since last installation, skipping installation of D:\Android\Exercise\android-testing-step-1-5\app\build\outputs\apk\prod\debug\app-prod-debug.apk
No apk changes detected since last installation, skipping installation of D:\Android\Exercise\android-testing-step-1-5\app\build\outputs\apk\androidTest\prod\debug\app-prod-debug-androidTest.apk
Running tests

$ adb shell am instrument -w -r   -e debug false -e class 'com.example.android.testing.notes.notes.NotesScreenTest#addNoteToNotesList' com.example.android.testing.notes.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
Client not ready yet..
Started running tests

android.support.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'scroll RecyclerView to: holder with view: has descendant: with text: is "UI testing for Android"' on view 'with id: com.example.android.testing.notes:id/notes_list'.
at android.support.test.espresso.PerformException$Builder.build(PerformException.java:82)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:79)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:51)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.waitForAndHandleInteractionResults(ViewInteraction.java:312)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.desugaredPerform(ViewInteraction.java:173)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:114)
at com.example.android.testing.notes.notes.NotesScreenTest.addNoteToNotesList(NotesScreenTest.java:128)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:527)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4.run(AndroidJUnit4.java:101)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:56)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:384)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2106)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Found 0 items matching holder with view: has descendant: with text: is "UI testing for Android", but position -1 was requested.
at android.support.test.espresso.contrib.RecyclerViewActions$ScrollToViewAction.perform(RecyclerViewActions.java:361)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$SingleExecutionViewAction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:356)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.doPerform(ViewInteraction.java:248)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.access$100(ViewInteraction.java:63)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call(ViewInteraction.java:153)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call(ViewInteraction.java:150)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)

Tests ran to completion.
```

I don't know what happened. The doc say to turn it off but it make the test fail. How can this happened ?

Comment: Can you post your test code?

Comment: This is the [test file](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-testing/blob/final/app/src/androidTest/java/com/example/android/testing/notes/notes/NotesScreenTest.java), my test code is the same as that file

Comment: According to the error log, it fails to scroll because it can't find any matching item. But it passes when you have animation turned on, so it is very likely that there could be delay in your code to populate data on your RecyclerView, say with `Handler.postDelayed`. You may need to use `IdlingResource` or subtle delay in your test code to fix the issue.

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same issue. Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Nope, I still need to enable the animation